# Hours worked over base

Tags: excel-formula

I have been stuck writing a formula for the below

45 HOURS * 52 WEEKS DIVIDED BY 12 MONTHS

I need this represented in hours so we can calculate our drivers overtime over their base hours

Attempted

(45/52)/12 but know its wrong

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: 195 hours s what I would expect

Comment: What about 45*52/12?